# Forward must problem explanation in compiler design

Tags: compilers

While studying, I came across the following statements:

A **join point** is a program point where two branches meet.

**Available expressions** is a forward, must problem.

**Forward** = Data Flow from in to out.

**Must** = At joint point, property must hold on all paths that are joined.

I get what joint point, available expression and forward is. But I am getting what exactly is meant by **MUST**.

Someone please explain what **MUST** is with **example**.

Edit: Could you please relate your statement with the following example.

[image: Available Expressions]

Answer (score 2):

I typically think of *must* as meaning *logical and*.

In the case of available expressions, when you reach a join point, the expression in question is *available* at the join point if and only if the expression is available on *all* of the input edges to the join point.  That is: if the expression is available on the first input edge, *and* it is available on the second input edge, *and* it is available on the third input edge, etc.

There are other properties, such as "could be a null pointer" which are *may* properties instead of *must* properties.  *May* I think of as meaning *logical or*.